# Localize DevExtreme widget

Tags: angular, devextreme

In my application it is possible to change the language without reloading the page.

So, when the user change the language, I need to update the locale of the **DevExtreme** widgets (for example the months label in the calendar widget).

In the documentation I found methods like the following:

```
Globalize.locale(navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage);


DevExpress.localization.locale(navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage);
```

But I can't import `Globalize` nor `DexExpress` in my component.

Is there an other way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think that both the Globalize and DevExpress namespaces should be in the global scope? In that case you would not have to add them to your component

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to localize my devextreme components: In `app.module` right in the import statements:

```
import {locale} from 'devextreme/localization';
```

And then before declaring the module, setting the locale like this:

```
locale(navigator.language);
```

You could try to call this at runtime, but I have doubts that it will update the locale in the components automatically.